# Fill encrypted login/password field ID with Perl's WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, field, www-mechanize, encryption

I would like to view my account balance (online banking) with a Perl script using WWW::Mechanize. The site is [Sparkasse Duerenen (online banking)](https://bankingportal.sparkasse-dueren.de/portal/portal/Starten) However, the field IDs seem to have a special encryption mechanism. On each new page load the id is generated with a new unique name.

If you view the HTML source you will see following in the field "Legimtation ID" located on the left where you can input login data.

```
  <input id="TgQZqInrKGXTjHOP" class="loginfeld" type="text" onkeyup="testEmptyInput(event,this);" onblur="testEmptyInput(event,this);" onfocus="testEmptyInput(event,this);" value="" maxlength="16" size="10" name="TgQZqInrKGXTjHOP"></input>
```

Same thing on the PIN/Password.

The input ID seems to have every time an unique generated name. I'am not able to fill this field with a static pre-defined field-name with WWW::Mechanize. What would you folks suggest now? How to fill this field in order to submit a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting using [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) to parse the returned HTML and look for an input with `class="loginfeld"` and `type="text"`.  Then just pull the attribute `name`.

For a short 8 minute video on using `Mojo::DOM` check out [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

The following prints the login field names to STDOUT.  You'll just have to feed the return html from `WWW::Mechanize` to `Mojo::DOM` instead of this method of using `Mojo::UserAgent`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://bankingportal.sparkasse-dueren.de/portal/portal/Starten';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = $ua->get($url)->res->dom;

# Print Login field names
for my $input ($dom->find('input')->each) {
    if ($input->attr('class') eq 'loginfeld') {
        if ($input->attr('type') eq 'text') {
            print "Login field name = " . $input->attr('name') . "\n";
        }
        if ($input->attr('type') eq 'password') {
            print "Password field name = " . $input->attr('name') . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question though: Why they encrypt the element IDs in the HTML source? What's the name for that type of security and is that considered as a good security type? I have not seen it before.

Comment: Security through obfuscation, perhaps?

Comment: @user3606329 I strongly suspect that the random ID is trying to prevent password managers from storing the login information for that site, and in a later session making the login information available to unauthorized users. While this measure doesn't guarantee security, it can be seen as an attempt to strengthen the overall security via obfuscation.